# Hibernate - join un related objects

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a requirement, wherein I have to join two unrelated objects using Hibernate HQL.
Here is the sample POJO class

```
class Product{
int product_id;        
String name;
String description;
}
```

and

```
Class Item{
int item_id;
String name;
String description;
int quantity;
int product_id; //Note that there is no composed product object.
}
```

Now I want to perform a query like
select * from Product p left outer join Item i on p.product_id = i.item_id

I want a multidimensional array as an output of this query so that I can have separate instances of Product and Item, instead of one composed in another.
Is there any way to do this in Hibernate?

Answer (score 5):

It is uncommon to represent an association between objects by storing the id of the associated object, rather than the associated object itself. Storing the object is more expressive and type safe, and need not have a performance impact since hibernate features lazy loading proxies.

But of course you can join things not mapped as associations in the mapping file. Quoting the [hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from):

> Multiple classes can appear, resulting
>   in a cartesian product or "cross"
>   join.
>
> ```
> from Formula, Parameter
>
> from Formula as form, Parameter as param
> ```

[and](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)

> Queries can return multiple objects
>   and/or properties as an array of type
>   Object[]:
>
> ```
> select mother, offspr, mate.name
> from DomesticCat as mother
>     inner join mother.mate as mate
>     left outer join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```
>
> Or as a List:
>
> ```
> select new list(mother, offspr, mate.name)
> from DomesticCat as mother
>     inner join mother.mate as mate
>     left outer join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```
>
> Or - assuming that the class Family
>   has an appropriate constructor - as an
>   actual typesafe Java object:
>
> ```
> select new Family(mother, mate, offspr)
> from DomesticCat as mother
>     join mother.mate as mate
>     left join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```
>
> You can assign aliases to selected
>   expressions using as:
>
> ```
> select max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n
> from Cat cat
> ```
>
> This is most useful when used together
>   with select new map:
>
> ```
> select new map( max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n )
> from Cat cat
> ```
>
> This query returns a Map from aliases
>   to selected values.

Combining this with a simple where clause, we get:

```
select product, item
from Product product, Item item
where item.product_id = product.product_id
```

**Edit**: I missed that you want an *outer* join. In that case I don't know a way other than mapping the association so you can do an ordinary join on it. Note that this does not necessitate a particular form of the query result, i.e. you can still do:

```
select product, item
from Item item
left join item.product as product
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround to join over ids in hql [here](http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/hibernate_hql_inner_join_on_clause).

However, i recommend using a native sql query here.

Comment: Quoting from your link: "Although this [cross join with ,] will compile fine I did not pursue this solution so can't really comment on its effectiveness. I abandoned it because it just felt wrong. But it should work." Is this the reason for your recommendation? It *felt wrong*?

Comment: no that is not. When working with hql, i expect joining over associations, not over ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subselect

```
 from Product p where p.product_id in (select item_id from Item)
```

Comment: 1. You mean (select product_id from Item) don't you? 2. This is not an outer join, as products without items won't be returned. 3. This does not return the items joined even though that is specifically requested by CuriousMind.

Comment: @meriton 1. No, i mean *p.product_id in (select item_id from Item)* because the question is clear *on p.product_id = i.item_id* 2 and 3. Yes, i know, Item instances will not be returned because he did not used *fetch* clause. So i suppose he just want to retrieve plain Product instances

Comment: 1.: Ah you're right. Probably a bug in the question - why would he join on item_id when he has a product_id column? But then, who knows, perhaps he really wants such a strange join condition ...

Answer (score 0):

Try subselect in select clause:

```
select p, (select i from Item where p.product_id = i.item_id) from Product p
```